# How can I create a JOIN using USING in ZF2

Tags: zend-framework2, zend-db

I'm supporting 2 different websites.  One uses the default Zend libraries in /usr/share (v 1.12) and the other uses specifically installed Zend libraries, which are v 2.3.

I'm trying to copy some code across from one setup to another and have encountered a problem, that ->joinUsing( is not defined in ZF2.

So can someone tell me how I can create a join, using Zend/Db in ZF2, that joins 2 tables using a USING, such that the 2nd instance of the joined column, doesn't get in the way of the query.

Answer (score 2):

ZF2 just has a `join()` function, with an optional parameter to supply if you want a specific join type. See http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.3/en/modules/zend.db.sql.html#join for an example.

Note that ZF2 is not backward compatible with ZF1, so if you haven't realised this already, you'll need to make a number of changes to get the ZF1 code working.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I thought.  Annoying, as I find using ON where both fields are the same name, untidy, but needs must :-)